# Eloquent issue in Blade Template

Tags: laravel

I have a function in my controller like below

```
 public function singleCategory($id){
    if($id == 'all') {
        $category = Category::get();
    } else {
        $category = Category::find($id);
    }
    return view('campaigns_by_category', compact('category'));
}
```

In blade template I am using below code

```
 @if(request()->segment(2) == 'all')
                @php
                    foreach($category as $cat) {
                        $campaigns = $cat->users()->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(20);
                    }
                @endphp
            @else
                @php
                    $campaigns = $category->users()->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(20); 
                @endphp
            @endif
            {{ count($campaigns) }}  // why I am getting 0 here ?
```

Comment: did you define a relationship between users and category?

Comment: can you define user relationship on your `Category` modal?

Answer (score 1):

Laravel relationship works like the following way:
Define the relationship between Category and User in `Category` Modal.

```
class Category extends Model
{
   function users() {
      return $this->hasMany('App\User');
   }
}
```

I hope you will understand.
If not than read laravel eloquent relationship
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Thanks @Amit Senjaliya. I have below code in my model `public function users(){
        return $this->hasMany(User::class)->whereActive_status(1)->whereUser_type('user');
}` . Thanks.

Comment: Why I am getting 0 as result below ? `@if(request()->segment(2) == 'all') @php foreach($category as $cat) { $campaigns = $cat->users()->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(20); } @endphp @else @php $campaigns = $category->users()->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(20); @endphp @endif {{ count($campaigns) }}`

Comment: @abuabu What is `whereActive_status()` and `whereUser_type()` ?

Comment: These are Database field.

Comment: Then it should be like this: `$this->hasMany(User::class)->where("Active_status", "1")->where("User_type", 'user');`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199837/discussion-between-amit-senjaliya-and-abu-abu).

Answer (score 1):

Because when you do `->get()` or `->all()` `$category` become a **collection** of `Category`, not a `Category`

```
@if(request()->segment(2) == 'all')
   @php
        foreach($category as $cat) {
          $campaigns = $cat->users()->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(20);
        }
    @endphp
@else
    @php
          $campaigns = $category->users()->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(20); 
    @endphp
@endif 

@if($campaigns->count() > 0)
    // some code here
@endif
```

Edit;

As you asked *But Why I am getting 0 as result below ?*
The part below will overwrite `$campaigns` since you're in a foreach

```
foreach($category as $cat) {
    $campaigns = $cat->users()->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(20);
}
```

May a suggest you something different

```
 public function singleCategory($id){

    // Eager loading the users before will increase the performance, by performing one single query instead of repeting the query in a loop
    $query = Category::with(['users' => function($query) {
        $query->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(20);
    }])


    if($id == 'all') {
        $categories = $query->get();
    } else {
        // findOrFail() will throw a 404 when the ID doesn't not exists
        // [$id] is an array to return a Collection of Category
        $categories = $query->findOrFail([$id]);
    }
    return view('campaigns_by_category', compact('categories'));
}
```

Then in your blade, you don't need to know if you have one or more categories.

```
@foreach($categories as $category)

 {{-- "In my knowledge we can't alias with eager loading, but you can still make a relationshion campaigns instead of users" --}}
    {{ $category->users->count() }}

    {{-- "forelse is like a foreach but perform a `else` when users are empty" --}}
    @forelse($category->users as $campaign)
        {{ $campaign }}
    @empty
        No campaigns for {{ $category }}
    @endforelse

@foreach
```

Comment: Thanks @cbaconnier. Your solution is working. But Why I am getting 0 as result below ?

`@if(request()->segment(2) == 'all')
                    @php
                        foreach($category as $cat) {
                            $campaigns = $cat->users()->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(20);
                        }
                    @endphp
                @else
                    @php
                        $campaigns = $category->users()->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(20); 
                    @endphp
                @endif
                {{ count($campaigns) }}`

Comment: I am getting error in below line. `$categories = $query::get();  // [2019-09-23 12:25:24] laravel.ERROR: Non-static method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::get() should not be called statically` .

Comment: `@if(request()->segment(2) == 'all')
                    @php
                        foreach($category as $cat) {
                            $campaigns = $cat->users()->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(20);
                        }
                    @endphp
                @else
                    @php
                        $campaigns = $category->users()->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(20); 
                    @endphp
                @endif
                {{ count($campaigns) }}` I would like to catch the value from the `foreach` loop.

Comment: @abuabu I fixed `::`, it was a small typo I didn't tested in real life sorry for that.  About your campaigns, I moved it **inside** the foreach. Since you have **many campaigns|users**, which one would you count then?